# Exception thrown whilst inserting data into an access database using the command "insert into"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, oledbcommand, oledbexception

I'm working on a project for a college course I'm currently on and I'm having some trouble trying to insert data into a database from an application developed in Visual Studio 2017. I've already connected to the database and am able to open it from the application.

The issue arises when I try to enter data into the table. I get a syntax error. Usually this means there an issue with the actual command right? Well i thought about this and created a new database, and another project and got the inert into command working for that one. At this point , a week of trying to get it to work, I'm stuck and desperately need help. Here is the code I'm using to try and add data to the table.

```
try 
{
     Form1.DataBaseConnection.Open();
} 
catch (Exception E) 
{
     MessageBox.Show("!!ATTENTION!! - Error accessing database. Please restart the application. ::::" + E.ToString());    
     Form1.DataBaseConnection.Close(); 
}

OleDbCommand DataBaseAddEntry = new OleDbCommand();
DataBaseAddEntry.Connection = Form1.DataBaseConnection;

DataBaseAddEntry.CommandText = "insert into Shoe(Size, Type, Name) values('" + int.Parse(TxtBoxSize.Text) + "','" + TxtBoxType.Text + "','" + TxtBoxName.Text + "')";

DataBaseAddEntry.ExecuteNonQuery();

Form1.DataBaseConnection.Close();
RefreshDataGridView();
```

As a side not, I didn't design the database or create it. I have to work in a team and the database was created by another member. So when I created my own database it worked fine. Could it be something to do with the actual database and not the code?

Comment: Size is a reserved keyword in MS-Access, you need square brackets around it. But you really need to change this code and use parameters when you create sql commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the single quotes from the value for **Size**, as this looks like it should be an int types.

```
DataBaseAddEntry.CommandText = "insert into Shoe([Size], [Type], [Name]) values(" + int.Parse(TxtBoxSize.Text) + ",'" + TxtBoxType.Text + "','" + TxtBoxName.Text + "')";
```

Also, as the comment suggests, you should use [parameterized SQL](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) and consider wrapping the try block over the whole database operation, and not only the attempt to **open**.

Comment: Thank you so much! The application is now doing exactly what it is meant to do. I did have a try catch block around the part where i tried to add an entry to the database but i removed it in the hope of receiving a little bit more information for the error. I'll also look into the parameterised SQL